# gvim how to open different FileTypes in different color schemes

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc, color-theme

okay so I want gvim to open all my files using the 'slate' color scheme except for .html and .css files. I want it to open .html and .css files using the 'ron' color scheme. I tried doing

```
colo slate
autocmd FileType html colorscheme ron
autocmd FileType css colorscheme ron
```

but it didn't work, it still opens .html and .css files using slate. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: The colorscheme is a global setting--it applies to all windows/buffers. You can't do what you want using colorschemes. However, you _can_ modify the html and css syntax files to use colors you specify explicitly rather than using the color names they link to.

Comment: Hm okay and where can I find the html and css syntax files to change the colors which are being used?

Comment: They are in the $VIMRUNTIME/syntax directory, and have file names html.vim and css.vim. The value of $VIMRUNTIME depends on your system, but you can use it in a command such as `:e $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/html.vim`. You'll see lines at the bottom such as `HtmlHiLink HtmlPreStmt PreProc`. `PreProc` (or `preproc`) is a highlight group whose color is defined in `$VIMRUNTIME/colors/ron.vim`. If you copy `html.vim` to `~/.vim/syntax` and edit the copy to define `HtmlPreStmt` as the colors used by `ron`, e.g., `hi HtmlPreStmt guifg=Pink2` and so on, you should get the coloring you want.

Comment: Hm okay interesting, is there a way to just turn off the error highlighting which 'slate' (a gvim color scheme) uses? because that's really the only reason I don't want to use slate for html and css, because I don't like the error highlighting it gives and I want to disable it. Will I be able to disable error highlighting using the $VIMRUNTIME you talked about above?

Comment: I just added the answer to this to your other question that also asks this.

Comment: I'm sure @garyjohn enjoyed wasting his time on this beautiful case of XY problem.

Comment: @romainl what do you mean by 'beautiful case of XY problem'?

Comment: You want to do X and you think that doing Y will help you but you can't make Y work and you ask for help on Y without talking about X at all, making everyone involved loose his time. Classic.